# If you use horseradish for maror, must it be red (or purple)?

Tags: passover, marror-bitter-herbs

I am somewhat familiar with the arguments about horseradish vs lettuce (or other stalks that leak white fluid) for *maror*.  Disregarding that, assuming you follow the tradition allowing horseradish as *maror*, someone told me it has to be the "red" (or purple) kind of horseradish, with beet juice mixed in to color it.  They gave me no explanation at the time they said this.

Is it true? If so, why? If not, any guesses why someone might think this?

Comment: I've never heard of using celery for maror. Do you have a source for that? If there is such an opinion it would mean one should not use celery for karpas.

Comment: I don't know of any sources about beet juice, but note the only Mishna which gives laws of Maror ([Pesachim 2:6](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%A4%D7%A1%D7%97%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%91_%D7%95)) explicitly excludes "[pickled, stewed, or boiled](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9670&st=&pgnum=169)" versions of whichever plant is chosen.

Comment: @Double AA, maybe I mispoke.  I did say I was only somewhat familiar... *embarrassed*  I'll edit the question to rephrase.  Maybe the red version in the store isn't pickled, and the white version is?  That would make sense... although I don't know if that's true, either.

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Answer (score 1):

You can't use prepared horseradish, the kind that is red or white, for maror.  If you're using horseradish, it has to be raw horseradish.

https://www.yeshiva.co/ask/58749

Answer (score 0):

From what I know, it doesn't need to be red. I personally use white horseradish every year, and I know many who do so as well. It is possible one would think this due to a combination of them not knowing any different, and seeing something about us eating certain foods on pesach to remember the blood of the jews in egypt.

Comment: What foods are eaten on pesach to remember the blood of the Jews in Egypt?

Comment: Welcome to MiYodeya and thanks for this first answer. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) for a guide which might help understand the site. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: @DoubleAA The wine on pesach is supposed to be red to commemorate the blood of the jewish children that pharaoh killed, the dam milah, and the blood of the lamb that was spread on the doorposts.

Comment: @DoubleAA I wonder does it have to be from red grapes or is it good enough from white grapes coloured red by red grape peel. I understand that kedem does that.

Comment: @interested Red grapes are white on the inside with red peels. Meaning all red wine is colored by the peels of red grapes.

Comment: @DoubleAA Ok but can you colour grapes with green on the outside red.

Comment: @interested If you mix in red grape peels, it'll come out red. If you smash red grapes and take out the peels, it won't be red. If you smash non-red grapes and mix in some red peels, it'll be red. If you mash a mix of colors of grapes and leave in the red peels, it'll be red. If you take out the red peels, it won't be.

Comment: @DoubleAA I understand. My question is, is it enough that the wine colour is red or does it also have to come from red grapes

Comment: @interested I don't know about food coloring, but colored with red grape peels is clearly fine since that's how all wine is colored.